# VBA multiple variable search

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to search through a large table that has many cases and return a value for it [I've tried Index/Match and Vlookup, but since there are many different Market variables, I can't get it to work]

Template Link [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4sKjkAZVkt6YzVSUHFwQnRFVk0/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the main-input Excel table. The important factors in this table are "Client ID, Currency, Market" (input by user).

[image]

Using these three variables, I want to search through this list, and return the MIN value in the main-input table. **As you can see, there are certain cases where 2/3 of the variables are the same.**

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub komisijas_calc_Click()

'Declare the variables
Dim klienta_nr As Long
Dim ISIN As String
Dim Cena As Double
Dim Skaits As Double
Dim Komisija As Double
Dim vk As String
Dim Summa As Double
Dim kSheet As Worksheet

Dim lngFirstRow As Long: lngFirstRow = 2
Dim lngLastRow  As Long
Dim lngCol      As Long: lngCol = 2
Dim lngCounter  As Long
Dim lngKom As Long: lngKom = 11




Set kSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("spec_klienti")


With Worksheets(1)
    lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lngCol).End(xlUp).Row

    For lngCounter = lngFirstRow To lngLastRow

    klienta_nr = Range("B" & lngCounter).Value
    ISIN = Range("E" & lngCounter).Value
    Cena = Range("H" & lngCounter).Value
    Skaits = Range("I" & lngCounter).Value
    vk = Range("D" & lngCounter).Value
    Summa = Cena * Skaits


Select Case klienta_nr



    Case 1
                '(Vācija, Francija, Nīderlandes, Itālija, Īrija) - 30 EUR MIN
                If klienta_nr = 1 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IE") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.01
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = Komisija
                        End If
                If klienta_nr = 636092 And Komisija <= 30 Then
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = 30
                        End If


                If klienta_nr = 1 And (Left(ISIN, 2) <> "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "IE") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.003
                    If Komisija >= 40 Then
                        .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = 40
                            End If
                        End If


    Case 2
                '(Vācija, Francija, Nīderlandes, Itālija, Īrija) - 30 EUR MIN
                If klienta_nr = 2 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IE") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.01
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = Komisija
                        End If
                'Set 30 EUR Min
                If klienta_nr = 2 And Komisija <= 30 Then
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = 30
                        End If

                If klienta_nr = 2 And (Left(ISIN, 2) <> "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "IE") Then
                    GoTo AllElseFails
                        End If


Case Else

     AllElseFails:

              'IP2, 0.03% komisija, 40 EUR/USD Max
                If Right(vk, 1) = 1 Or Right(vk, 1) = 8 Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.003
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = Komisija
                        End If
              'IP1, 0.1% komisija, 40 EUR/USD Max
                If Right(vk, 1) = 7 Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.01
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = Komisija
                        End If
                'Komisija MAX is 40, so anything >=40 equals 40
                If Komisija >= 40 Then
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = 40
                        End If
            'End If
  End Select
 Next lngCounter
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: so you want to find the smallest MIN? how do you calculate the MIN with these three variables?

Comment: I just want to return the MIN, which is the last Column in the second image. So, for example (in the first image I put in client ID 111111, Currency EUR, and DE) I need this to return min 30.

Comment: do you already have code? can you post it?

Comment: @AmirKrasnic edited, however code isn't necessary here. I'm trying to do it through Excel functions.

Comment: I still do not get what you really want to do here, where in your code do you want the MIN to be returned and to where shall it be returned?

Comment: @AmirKrasnic In this example I'm not using VBA. I simply want to return the MIN from the Table in the second image by using the (Client ID, Currency, and Market) variables that are inputed in Table (first image). I tried using Index/Match and Vlookup, but since there are many different variables, it doesn't go through.

Comment: Can you share the workbook template?

Comment: @nishitdey https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4sKjkAZVkt6YzVSUHFwQnRFVk0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Nikoljs : Sheet cannot be accessed

Comment: YOu can use the database for this, it will be much easier